# Lovász Local Lemma for existence of a graph coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am reading about Lovász Lemma ([in these notes](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efelsner/Lehre/SemProbMeth/01c-MR-Chapt_4.pdf)). In the Remark below Theorem 4.3 the it is claimed that we can extend the allowed number to $\frac{l}{2e}$ by using the more general version of the LLL (wikipedia calls it the [asymmetric one](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efelsner/Lehre/SemProbMeth/01c-MR-Chapt_4.pdf)). Could you please tell me how to prove this?

> Remark: Here $e$ denotes Euler's number.

[image]

Comment: These are not *notes*. These are a chapter of Molloy and Reed's *Graph Colouring and the Probabilistic Method*. You should give proper attribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "more precise version of the Local Lemma" does not refer to the asymmetric version; rather, it refers to the version which checks the inequality $ep(d+1)\le 1$ rather than the inequality $4pd \le 1$. (In Molloy and Reed, this is Remark 4.1.)

The proof using this version is almost identical. With the condition that each color is acceptable for $\frac{\ell}{2e}$ neighbors of any one vertex, we argue that $|E_x| \le \frac{\ell^2}{2e}$ and $|E_y| \le \frac{\ell^2}{2e}$.

The one extra detail that needs to be supplied is that $E_x$ and $E_y$ both contain the event $A_{i,e}$ that we're looking at - which we don't need to count in $d$. Therefore $A_{i,e}$ is mutually independent of all but at most $\frac{\ell^2}{e}$ events **counting itself**. This means we are allowed to set $d = \frac{\ell^2}{e}-1$, and satisfy the inequality $ep(d+1) \le 1$ needed to apply the Local Lemma.